# Using the state of a gpio in an if condition

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream, gpio

I have a function and inside that function I am using usleep(). However, I would only like to use usleep() under the condition that a certain gpio has a value of zero. Here is the code I have so far:

```
const char *const amplifierGPIO = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio107/value";
const char *const hardwareID = "/sys/class/gpio/gpiox/value";

    bool isWM8750()
    {
      std::ifstream id(hardwareID);
      if (id.is_open())
      {
        const char *const value;
        id >> value;

        if (value == "0")
        {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    void amplifierUnmute()
    {
      std::ofstream amp(amplifierGPIO);
      if (amp.is_open())
      {
        amp << "1";
        amp.close();
      }

      if(isWM8750())
      {
        usleep(50000);
      }
    }
```

I am getting an error I am not sure how to resolve:

```
sound_p51.cpp:38: error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'id >> value'
sound_p51.cpp:40: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour
```

Comment: Change `const char *const value;` to `std::string value;`

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Ah I see, this is because hardwareID is declared as a pointer? So saying: const char *const value; is just another pointer and I can't just compare two pointers?

Comment: It is generally hard to write to a constant.

Comment: _@Rob_ Besides what @user4581301 said, yes.

Comment: Comparing two pointers will literally compare the pointers. Does Address on the left match address on the right? If so, then true. It does not consider what the pointers reference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to put data into a const char* const variable. A const char* const is a pointer to a string where the pointer can not change, and the string data that is pointed to can not change, hence the const's.

The warning is because there is no overloaded == operator for const char*. For this type of comparison generally you will use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

However, since you are using c++, you probably want to use a `std::string` which should solve both of the referenced compiler messages like so:

```
#include <string>
// ...
bool isWM8750()
    {
      std::ifstream id(hardwareID);
      if (id.is_open())
      {
        std::string value;
        id >> value;
        id.close();

        if (value == "0")
        {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Some more examples with raspberry pi gpios here: http://www.hertaville.com/introduction-to-accessing-the-raspberry-pis-gpio-in-c.html